# Maven assembly package with only project and dependant jar

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a parent project with 2 submodules. I want to create a package with just project and dependant jars. Problem i am facing is all source files[java,scripts, configs] also get included in the artifact, can somebody help how to achieve this.
Following is the descriptor i am using:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>binaries</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <includes>
                <include>*:sub1</include>
                <include>*:sub2</include>
            </includes>
            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>${artifactId}</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>true</unpack>
                <unpackOptions>
                    <excludes>                      
                        <exclude>**/resources/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/docs/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/src/**</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </unpackOptions>
                <dependencySets>
                    <dependencySet>
                        <outputDirectory>${artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
                        <unpack>false</unpack>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependencySet>
                </dependencySets>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>

</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use this kind of assembly descriptor:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>xyz</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
          <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
          <useTransitiveDependencies>true</useTransitiveDependencies>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
          <unpack>false</unpack>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>${project.groupId}:*:*</exclude>
          </excludes>
      </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>modules</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Based on your descriptor i would suggest to use `<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>` cause you prefixed all ouputDirectories with `${artifactId}`.

The above descriptor will create a zip file which contains sub-folders lib which contains the dependencies and a folder `modules` which contains the modules of your multi-module build.
Furthermore i would suggest to create a [separate module which is responsible for creating the archive](https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-examples/tree/master/assemblies-with-modules-and-deps).

If your resulting zip contains java source files etc. it sounds you are doing the assembly step within a module which is of packaging `jar`.

Comment: Thanks.Your descriptor did the job.